# Hashing username/password values during asp.net forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, hash

I am working on an asp.net web site and I am using .NET authentication framework to create  secure page that requires username/password for loging in.  As far as I can understand, the .NET forms authentication sends encoded value of the username/password to the server where  hashed values of the password is stored in ms sql server database (assuming that paswordFormat is set to Hashed in the web.config file).

So, what I want to do now is take username/password values from the login page hash them using any of the Hash algorithms in the client, send them to server and do the verification process in the server. Is there anyone who comes across such situation or if there are related resources or workarounds. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it from the server as

```
 Private Function isValidUser(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As [Boolean]

    Dim UserHash As String =FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(username, "MD5")
```

If you want to do something on the client then u have to use javascript; here's a useful article
http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html